# Assertion failed (type == CV_32FC1 || type == CV_64FC1) in dct

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to take dct of an image. At first I was getting error

> The function/feature is not implemented (Odd-size DCT's are not implemented) in dct

So I pad the image with zeros to make it even sized

But now I get error:

> Assertion failed (type == CV_32FC1 || type == CV_64FC1) in dct

How can I solve this? Below is what I'm doing in python

```
    img = cv2.imread(filepath)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    ret,thresholded = cv2.threshold(gray,200,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

    img = cv2.cvtColor(thresholded, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
    gray = thresholded
    gray = gray.astype('float32')

    #padding
    BLUE = [255,0,0]
    rows,cols = gray.shape
    nrows = cv2.getOptimalDFTSize(rows)
    ncols = cv2.getOptimalDFTSize(cols)
    right = ncols - cols
    bottom = nrows - rows
    bordertype = cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT
    gray = cv2.copyMakeBorder(img,0,bottom,0,right,bordertype, value = 0)
    gray = gray.astype('float32')
    dct=cv2.dct(gray)
```

Comment: did you try http://answers.opencv.org/question/9578/how-to-get-dct-of-an-image-in-python-using-opencv/

Comment: doesnt `gray = cv2.copyMakeBorder(img,0,bottom,0,right,bordertype, value = 0)` create a 3 channel mat because you use img?!? probably it isnt grayscale anymore?

Answer (score 2):

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
img = cv2.imread('imgColor.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

ret,thresholded = cv2.threshold(gray,200,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

img = cv2.cvtColor(thresholded, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
gray = thresholded
gray = np.float32(gray)/255.0
dct=cv2.dct(gray)

#padding
# BLUE = [255,0,0]
# rows,cols = gray.shape
# nrows = cv2.getOptimalDFTSize(rows)
# ncols = cv2.getOptimalDFTSize(cols)
# right = ncols - cols
# bottom = nrows - rows
# bordertype = cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT
# gray = cv2.copyMakeBorder(img,0,bottom,0,right,bordertype, value = 0)
# gray = np.float32(gray)/255.0
# dct=cv2.dct(gray)
```

This worked for me ! Found this [here](http://answers.opencv.org/question/9578/how-to-get-dct-of-an-image-in-python-using-opencv/)